How to get rid of multiple gaps in my graph
I made a conclusion of the price chart bypassing the internal bars, it is necessary to display each subsequent price candle only when it updates the high or low of the previous one.
The main task has been solved, but now there are empty spaces on the chart.
How can I get rid of these gaps?
//@version=5
indicator("True Movement Price")

CandleColor     = close >= open ? color.rgb(0, 188, 212, 0) : color.rgb(0, 96, 100, 0)
WickcolorColor  = close >= open ? color.rgb(0, 188, 212, 0) : color.rgb(0, 96, 100, 0)
BorderColor     = close >= open ? color.rgb(0, 188, 212, 0) : color.rgb(0, 96, 100, 0)

var key = false

var PLow = low
var PHigh = high
var PClose = close
var POpen = open

if high > PHigh or low < PLow
    key := true
    PLow := low
    PHigh := high
    PClose := close
    POpen := open
else
    key := false

plotcandle(key ? POpen : na, key ? PHigh : na, key ? PLow : na, key ? PClose : na, color = CandleColor, bordercolor = BorderColor, wickcolor = WickcolorColor)

plothandle does not work inside the if construct and I do not know how to execute it only under the true condition that it does not work empty and does not create gaps



you can adjust your approach to continuously track and plot all necessary data points, but only display those candles where there is a true update (either a new high or a new low). The gaps occur because your current script plots na (not available) for periods where the condition isn't met, effectively leaving those time slots blank.
Here’s a refined version:
//@version=5
indicator("True Movement Price", overlay=true)

var float PLow = na
var float PHigh = na
var float PClose = na
var float POpen = na

if (high > PHigh or low < PLow or na(PLow))
    PLow := low
    PHigh := high
    PClose := close
    POpen := open

CandleColor = close >= open ? color.rgb(0, 188, 212) : color.rgb(0, 96, 100)
WickcolorColor = close >= open ? color.rgb(0, 188, 212) : color.rgb(0, 96, 100)
BorderColor = close >= open ? color.rgb(0, 188, 212) : color.rgb(0, 96, 100)

plotcandle(POpen, PHigh, PLow, PClose, color = CandleColor, bordercolor = BorderColor, wickcolor = WickcolorColor)

or
//@version=5
indicator("True Movement Price2", overlay=true)

CandleColor = close >= open ? color.rgb(0, 188, 212) : color.rgb(0, 96, 100)
WickColor = close >= open ? color.rgb(0, 188, 212) : color.rgb(0, 96, 100)
BorderColor = close >= open ? color.rgb(0, 188, 212) : color.rgb(0, 96, 100)

plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color=CandleColor, wickcolor=WickColor, bordercolor=BorderColor, title="Colored Candlestick")

Explanation:

Initialization: Variables PLow, PHigh, PClose, and POpen are initialized as na and updated only when a new high or low is observed. This ensures that candles always have some value and are not set to na, which causes gaps.

Condition Check: The if-condition checks if the current high is greater than PHigh, the current low is lower than PLow, or if PLow is na (for the first run). If true, it updates the values. This logic ensures that the first available candle is plotted and subsequent candles are plotted only on significant updates.

Plot Function: The plotcandle function plots the candles using the last updated values of open, high, low, and close. Since these variables retain their last significant values instead of resetting to na, the chart will not have gaps.



Yes, it works, but now several identical candles are being drawn. Perhaps it is possible not to draw them somehow? I have attached a new image to the post.
